# celery "retry" with updated arguments

Tags: python, celery

Considering a task takes a list as arguments and process each element in the list, which may succeed or fail. In this case, how to "retry" with the failed elements only?

Example:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def my_test(self, my_list:list):
    new_list = []
    for ele in my_list:
        try:
            do_something_may_fail(ele)
        except:
            new_list.append(ele)
    # how to retry with the new list?
    # like 
    # self.retry(my_list=new_list, countdown=5)
    # or
    # self.apply_async(new_list, countdown=5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution 1

Use [Task.retry](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.retry) with its `args` and `kwargs` input.

> **`retry(args=None, kwargs=None, exc=None, throw=True, eta=None, countdown=None, max_retries=None, **options)`**
>
> Retry the task, adding it to the back of the queue.
>
> Parameters
>
> **args** *(Tuple)* – Positional arguments to retry with.
>
> **kwargs** *(Dict)* – Keyword arguments to retry with.

Be aware when passing arguments because having a value just for the same parameter both in `args` and `kwargs` would result to failure. Below, I chose to only use `args=(<values here>)` and empty out `kwargs={}`. You may also opt to do the other way around where you would use `kwargs={<values here>}` and empty out `args=()`.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')


@app.task(
    bind=True,
    default_retry_delay=0.1,
    retry_backoff=False,
    max_retries=None,
)
def my_test(self, some_arg_1: int, my_list: list, some_arg_2: str):
    print(f"my_test {some_arg_1} {my_list} {some_arg_2}")

    # Filter the failed items. Here, let's say only the last item is successful.
    new_list = my_list[:-1]

    if new_list:
        self.retry(
            args=(
                some_arg_1 + 1,  # some_arg_1 increments per retry
                new_list,  # Failed items
                some_arg_2 * 2,  # some_arg_2's length doubles per retry
            ),
            kwargs={},  # Empty it out to avoid having multiple values for the arguments whether we initially called it with args or kwargs or both.
        )
```

**Logs (Producer)**

```
>>> from tasks import *
>>> my_test.apply_async(args=(0, [1,2,3,4,5], "a"))
<AsyncResult: 121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c>
>>>
>>> # The above command is just equivalent to the following (just the same result):
>>> # my_test.apply_async(kwargs={'some_arg_1': 0, 'my_list': [1,2,3,4,5], 'some_arg_2': "a"})
>>> # my_test.apply_async(args=(0,), kwargs={'my_list': [1,2,3,4,5], 'some_arg_2': "a"})
```

**Logs (Consumer)**

```
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,433: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] received
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,434: WARNING/MainProcess] my_test 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] a
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,434: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-25 21:32:06,438: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] retry: Retry in 0.1s
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,439: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] received
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,539: WARNING/MainProcess] my_test 1 [1, 2, 3, 4] aa
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,539: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-25 21:32:06,541: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] retry: Retry in 0.1s
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,542: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] received
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,640: WARNING/MainProcess] my_test 2 [1, 2, 3] aaaa
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,640: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-25 21:32:06,642: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] retry: Retry in 0.1s
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,643: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] received
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,742: WARNING/MainProcess] my_test 3 [1, 2] aaaaaaaa
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,743: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-25 21:32:06,745: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] retry: Retry in 0.1s
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,747: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] received
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,844: WARNING/MainProcess] my_test 4 [1] aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
[2021-08-25 21:32:06,844: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-25 21:32:06,844: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.my_test[121090c6-6b77-4cbd-b1d1-790005e8b18c] succeeded in 0.0005442450019472744s: None
```

- All task arguments are updated per retry:

  - `some_arg_1` increments by 1 per retry, from the starting value of `0` to the last value of `4`
  - `my_list` loses 1 item per retry, from the starting value of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to the last value of `[1]`
  - `some_arg_2` doubles it's size per retry, from the starting value of `"a"` to the last value of `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"`

## Solution 2

Just recall the same task from within the task itself, somewhat recursion-like.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')


@app.task
def my_test(some_arg_1: int, my_list: list, some_arg_2: str):
    print(f"my_test {some_arg_1} {my_list} {some_arg_2}")

    # Filter the failed items. Here, let's say only the last item is successful.
    new_list = my_list[:-1]

    if new_list:
        my_test.apply_async(
            args=(
                some_arg_1 + 1,  # some_arg_1 increments per retry
                new_list,  # Failed items
                some_arg_2 * 2,  # some_arg_2's length doubles per retry
            ),
            kwargs={},  # Empty it out to avoid having multiple values for the arguments whether we initially called it with args or kwargs or both.
        )
```

**Logs (Producer and Consumer)**

- Same as Solution 1