# Celery autoretry_for with Changed Arguments

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I would like for Celery to auto-retry failed tasks. I would like to use `autoretry_for` in the decorator, rather than an explicit `raise`.

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915407/celery-retry-with-updated-arguments) has a solution for the explicit `raise` case.

My code is meant to produce a `ZeroDivisionError` and retry with arguments 42 and .5 (to produce output of 84). Example: http://localhost:5001/divide/1/0 should produce a task that requires a retry and then produces a result of 84.

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.divide', max_retries=3, args=(42, .5), autoretry_for=(Exception,))
def divide(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x / y
```

The function produces a result of "division by zero" and a status of "FAILURE". How can I modify my code to retry with the new arguments?

I am running Celery 5.2 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
@celery.task(bind=True, name='tasks.divide', max_retries=3, autoretry_for=(Exception,), default_retry_delay=5)
def divide(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
    # time.sleep(5)
    if self.request.retries > 0:
        if y == 0:
            y = 0.0000000001
    print(f"x = {x}")
    print(f"y = {y}")
    return x / y
```

There are several things to note:

- I added `bind=True` to make the task a bound task. This gives access to the `self` object.
- It is possible to check whether the task is being retried by checking `self.request.retries > 0`.
- If the task is being retried, then I update the parameters. In this case, I changed `y = 0` to `y = 0000000001`.
- `args` in the decorator did not contribute to the solution and also did not allow me to retain the previous `x` value.

I am aware that there is another approach, but I have not finished researching it. Name, the use of a custom class derived from Task and that implements `on_failure`. [on_failure](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html)

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html